# Writing values to a .plist more than once?

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I have an iPhone App in the works, and I have a settings page within the app. I use a .plist to store the settings that the user picks, and then I read the data from the .plist later. This is not the -Info.plist that comes with it when you create the project, it is another plist file. When I tested the settings after coding it, it worked. The setting was able to be read, and it was the correct setting that I used. However, I went back to the settings in the same app-session, and changed the same setting. When I went to the app to see if it read the new setting, it only used the old (first) one. I tried again, but it yielded the same result. I am only able to write the setting once, and I cannot 'rewrite' or 'overwrite' the same setting. I cannot figure out what is wrong for the life of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overwrite or write to files in the app bundle itself. If you want to write to a file, you should first copy it to the app's Library or Documents directory, something like this:

```
NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathsForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistFile = @"myplist.plist";
NSString *plistInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistFile ofType:nil];
NSString *plistInDocsDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistFile];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:plistInBundle toPath:plistInDocsDir error:NULL];
// now `plistInDocsDir` is (over)writeable
```

However, for storing preferences of your app, it's better practice to use the [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Some string" forKey:@"MySettingKey"];
```

and/or create a [Preference Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) for your app.

Comment: can I store the NSUserDefaults into a .plist? Or is it better to just use it normally?

Comment: @apaperpixel The data in NSUserDefaults is already stored in a plist file. It's in a file in your app sandbox named Library/Preferences/com.mycompany.bundleid.plist.

Comment: So I can access the same NSUserDefaults from different .h and .m files?

Comment: @apaperpixel as it's a shared instance, yes. For the same application, all calls to NSUserDefaults access the same settings... **but come on, read the docs of NSUserDefaults!**